# PHP script to automate getting email

Tags: php, email

Here is what i try to do, almost like wordpress or video, i like to create/generate and pop email account on my server, where you can send email (text) or/and attached picture and automate the process of posting that on a blog, or just adding that to a folder for a slideshow.

Some time ago, i made a huge research about that, found some abstact solution that is more a concept that code/api or php script

So i am looking for a library, a api, a script et framework that can do that. PHP ot javascript favorised !

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

almost perfect solution

[Using PHP to read email in a POP3 mailbox](http://www.weberdev.com/get_example-4015.html)

and a download attachement solution [here](http://www.nerdydork.com/download-pop3imap-email-attachments-with-php.html)